# mysql select * where like current date

Tags: mysql

I tried this but why does this does not  work its neither giving me any error

```
select * from table where timestamp_field like '%select year(now())-select month(now())-select day(now())%'
```

Comment: timestamp field doesn not have such kind of string, there is only number

Comment: thanks for the comment so how can i do it the right way

Comment: what you want to extract?

Comment: '2014-09-20 16:17:36' my timestamp_field contains data like this

Comment: select * from table where timestamp_field like like '%2014-09-22%';
i have to achieve this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TRY

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE STR_TO_DATE(`timestamp_field`, "%Y-%m-%d") = CURDATE();
```

**Reference** : [MYSQL Date Time Function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

Comment: Your data has data that contains time as well as date, so matching any record to exactly `CURDATE()` is like hitting a bulls-eye at 600 meters with only one blunt dart. This solution alters the data so it can be compared to `CURDATE()` [but it isn't a "sargable" solution]

Comment: Yes you are right. It's not the stable solution. I just give it a hint how to work with mysql DATE funcions